# Probability mass function of two random variables

Tags: probability

Perform independent bernoulli trials, each of which is a success with probability $p$. Let $X_1$ be the number of failures preceding the first success and let $X_2$ be the number of failures between the first two successes. Find the joint mass function of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

#### Attempt

We have that

$$ P(X_1 = n) = (1-p)^n p $$

and

$$ P(X_2 = m ) = (1-p)^m p^2 $$

Since the trials are independent, we have

$$ P(X_1=n, X_2=m) = (1-p)^n (1-p)^m p^3 $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$ P(X_2 = m ) = (1-p)^m p^2 \qquad\color{red}\times $$

That would be the probability for $m$ consecutive failures and then two successes.

You don't want that.

You want the probability that, *after* the first success does happen (whenever it does), there are $m$ consecutive failures and then *one* success (the second).

$$ P(X_2 = m ) = (1-p)^m p^1 \qquad\color{green}\checkmark$$

All else is okay.

Answer (score 2):

The first $n$ are failures, followed by a success, followed by $m$ failures and a success.

By independence of each toss, the probability is

$$(1-p)^np(1-p)^mp=(1-p)^{m+n}p^2$$